# &lt is shown in place of '<' - WSO2 proxy service

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a webservice which returns XML string which in turn is captured by the callout mediator  and its been sent to a JMS queue. But when I see the content in the queue, the '<' symbol is being shown as '&lt' in activemq queue monitor.

Any ideas to solve this, I want to show it as '<' itself. Sample message below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://dummy.com.com/"><soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:validatePrescriptionResponse xmlns:ns2="http://dummy.com.com/"><return>&lt;Prescription xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  &lt;status value="active"/>
  &lt;patient>
    &lt;type value="Patient"/>
    &lt;url value="will smith"/>
  &lt;/patient>
  &lt;prescriber>
    &lt;type value="Provider"/>
    &lt;url value="Dr. stefan wright"/>
  &lt;/prescriber>
  &lt;prescribed value="2013+05:30"/>
  &lt;prescribed/>
  &lt;dispense>
    &lt;repeats value="10"/>
    &lt;quantity>
      &lt;value value="125"/>
      &lt;units value="ml"/>
    &lt;/quantity>
    &lt;dispenser>
      &lt;type value="Clinic"/>
      &lt;url value="Clinic"/>
    &lt;/dispenser&gt;
  &lt;/dispense>
  &lt;medicine>
    &lt;identification>
      &lt;text value="Penicillin VK oral suspension"/>
    &lt;/identification>
  &lt;/medicine>
  &lt;administrationRequest>
    &lt;description value="Penicillin VK oral suspension12510"/>
    &lt;totalPeriodicDose>
      &lt;numerator>
        &lt;value value="1250"/>
        &lt;units value="mg"/>
        &lt;code value="mg"/>
      &lt;/numerator>
      &lt;denominator>
        &lt;value value="1"/>
        &lt;units value="day"/>
        &lt;code value="d"/>
      &lt;/denominator>
    &lt;/totalPeriodicDose>
    &lt;duration>
      &lt;value value="10"/>
      &lt;units value="days"/>
      &lt;code value="d"/>
    &lt;/duration>
    &lt;dosageInstruction>
      &lt;doseQuantity>
        &lt;value value="125"/>
        &lt;units value="mg"/>
        &lt;code value="mg"/>
      &lt;/doseQuantity>
      &lt;schedule>
        &lt;repeat>
          &lt;frequency value="10"/>
          &lt;duration value="10"/>
        &lt;/repeat>
      &lt;/schedule>
    &lt;/dosageInstruction>
  &lt;/administrationRequest>
  &lt;reason>
    &lt;text value="Headache"/>
  &lt;/reason>
&lt;/Prescription></return></ns2:validatePrescriptionResponse>
   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help

-Guru
 @gnanagurus

Comment: It looks like something is putting a *string* as a *text node* which is *correctly being XML escaped*. Build XML correctly - if it comes from a string it will need to be [re]turned into proper XML (a DOM? a Node?) or otherwise bypass the (correct) XML emitter.

Answer (score 2):

Could you make sure you have set contentType correctly it should be "application/xml"

```
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
            <rules>
                <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
                <default>application/xml</default>
            </rules>
        </parameter>
```

Please refer below for the sample config.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="jms">
        <target>
            <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
            <outSequence>
                <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
        <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
            <rules>
                <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
                <default>application/xml</default>
            </rules>
        </parameter>
    </proxy>
</definitions>
```

The complete Artical can be accessed from [1].

[1].http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/11/wso2-esb-example-two-wayrequestresponse-semantic-jms

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Comment: Hello Dharshana, I verified my proxy service. But the content type is written as you mentioned. Any other idea ? - Guru

Comment: Could you try to retrieve data from the queue and check out. You can use the attached article to implemet this. Just put log level full for both posting and retrieve points to the queue. This will isolate the issue . I mostly suspect the issue is with the activemq queue monitor.

Comment: Hi Dharshana, I just tested the same use case with Apache JMeter. Even here I face the same problem. I feel its not because of the Browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you found the mentioned malformed XML messages in the JMS queue, which sent from ESB, i don't think it happened. because malformed xml messages can not be processed.
I think the issue is in your queue browser?
 It converts the xml tags < to `"&lt; "` .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking your external service through SOAPUI and see if it returns the response properly. Further add a log mediator just after the callout mediator with log level full and see if the constructed message is XML escaped as it is shown. This will help to isolate the issue. If possible paste your configuration too.

Answer (score 0):

This is my ESB proxy configuration: This is my proxy configuration:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ESBTESTProxy" transports="https,http,jms" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain"/>
         <class name="com.guru.test.HEALTH_Mediator"/>
         <callout serviceURL="http://localhost:8080/PrescriptionValidation/validate" action="urn:validatePrescription">
            <source xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
            <target xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
         </callout>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="jms:/OutputQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <drop/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8080/PrescriptionValidation/validate?wsdl"/>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>         
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>         
         <default>application/xml</default>      
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Let me know your thoughts.

-Guru
 @gnanagurus

Comment: remove the contenttype text/plain property after the callout mediator. You set that for a text message (hope your service is required that) after callout invocation set the correct content type/

Comment: Hello Ratha, I tried setting up the contentType as 'application/xml'. It doesn't work. Let me know your idea, I will get back if I find any solution for this. - Guru